# How to get precise result (not rounded result) in SQL Server 2008 R2 ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

i've been searching on google and this stackoverflow before asking this question and i haven't found any result that could solve my problem. Now I'm running out keywords to search more. I wish somebody here could help me with this.

Here is my problem :
I'm dealing with a lot of data and using SQL Server 2008 R2 as the database. I got some errors on the values of data and the cause is this similar query :

```
SELECT (SELECT 93834718293817283242347.982763509735278) * (SELECT 100/100)
```

The result is `93834718293817283242347.982764` and causing some incorrect value to my calculation. I want the result would be `93834718293817283242347.982763509735278` how do i do that?

I tried another way like this and still doesn't meet my expectation

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,15), 93834718293817283242347.982763509735278) * CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,15), (100/100))
```

The output is `93834718293817283242347.982764` but i want `93834718293817283242347.982763509735278`

And if you don't mind, i need some explanation for this. Thank you

Comment: why can't use substring and charindex to pick values and concatenate @Burhan Mubarok

Comment: The case can not use these trick, i used some calculation and multiplication.

Comment: it's almost 10 months now you are reacting ...awestruck

Comment: sory, i tried to search in other forum

Answer (score 2):

Actually I don't know how to solve this issue, but I give you some explanation of what happens. 
Well, lets look at properties of the values:

```
DECLARE @number SQL_VARIANT
SELECT @number =93834718293817283242347.982763509735278
SELECT @number
SELECT  
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@number, 'BaseType') BaseType,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@number, 'MaxLength') MaxLength,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@number, 'Scale') Scale,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@number, 'Precision') Precision
```

Second one:

```
DECLARE @number SQL_VARIANT
SELECT @number =100.0/100.0
SELECT @number
SELECT  
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@number, 'BaseType') BaseType,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@number, 'MaxLength') MaxLength,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@number, 'Scale') Scale,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@number, 'Precision') Precision
```

And multiplication

```
DECLARE @number SQL_VARIANT
SELECT @number =CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,15), 93834718293817283242347.982763509735278) * (100/100)
SELECT @number
SELECT  
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@number, 'BaseType') BaseType,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@number, 'MaxLength') MaxLength,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@number, 'Scale') Scale,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@number, 'Precision') Precision
```

Look at result carefully:

```
BaseType             MaxLength            Scale                Precision
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------
decimal              17                   6                    38
```

As you know, you can not declare **16** in Scale here `CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,15), 93834718293817283242347.982763509735278)`, otherwise you will get `Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.`.
So, in connection with folmulas [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187746.aspx) SQL Server can't add two values of scale and  beacause of that it use default scale **6**. Look at following example, it gives scale **5**:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,4), 93834718293817283242347.982763509735278) * CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,1), (100/100))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i am didn't find the solutin,